# Glob /* doesn't match files starting with dot

Tags: gulp, glob

I'm using gulp to copy all files from one dir to another using code like this:

```
gulp.src([ 'app/**/*' ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

Glob docs say `*` match all files, but in fact files which have names starting with dot, like `.gitignore`, are not copied.

How can it be worked around?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you add the option `dot: true`, it should work. Eg:

```
gulp.task('something', function () {
    return gulp.src([ 'app/**/*' ], {
        dot: true
    }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

[Reference](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#dots)

Answer (score 1):

For instances where the glob pattern is the only available interface. This pattern will do the trick:

```bash
**/{,.,.*/**/,.*/**/.}*
```

This expands to become the following globs:

```bash
**/*
**/.*
**/.*/**/*
**/.*/**/.*
```

You can add `app` to the beginning for `app/**/{,.,.*/**/,.*/**/.}*`.