# How can i matching FOLDERS the starting with dots using gulp?

Tags: path, gulp, matching, glob

How can i matching FOLDERS thet starting with dots using gulp?
Here is my gulpfile,
Maybe [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) can solve problem, but i cant understand how to implement it.

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(['**/sass/*.scss'], {dot: true})
        .pipe(cache('onlychanged'))
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 15 versions'],
            cascade: true
        }))
       .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
       .pipe(sass())
       .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(rename(function (filePath) {
            filePath.dirname = path.join(filePath.dirname, '../css/');
            return filePath;
        }))
        .pipe(debug({title: 'wt-monitor:'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glob /\* does't match files starting with dot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533843/glob-doest-match-files-starting-with-dot)

Comment: its working only for files(

Comment: No, it works for folders as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i have add and install glob `glob = require("glob")` and edited sources `return gulp.src(['**/sass/*.‌​scss'], {dot: true})` but still nothing working
@Sven Schoenung

Comment: sorry i cant understand what am i doing wrong, i tried with glob with dots true but its not working

So maybe i need to set sume setting for glob plugin?
@Sven Schoenung

Comment: yes its working thank you, i forget to add dot true to my watcher!